# Phpstorm superslow - 282.8% CPU usage

Tags: performance, svn, 32bit-64bit, phpstorm

After working for over 5 years with Netbeans I wanted to give a try with Phpstorm suggested by a friend.

I downloaded a fresh copy of Phpstorm and imported in the IDE a fresh project. The result is TERRIBLE!

1. Phpstorm is terribly slow during startup.
2. Doing an SVN commit take 5 minutes and keep CPU from 182.3% to 192%.
3. Editing a simple line of HTML like **Hello World** take 5 to 7 seconds just to type the first opening character "<".

Working in this situation is a disaster moreover if I'm working on a MacPro workstation with 8GB RAM with 2 Core Duo CPU.

I really don't understand what is causing the issue.
I attach a screenshot.
[image]

P.s.
Netbeans on the same workstation is flying!

Thanks in advance to all help and suggestion

Comment: Relevant: there is an official support forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/wi?view=discussions

Comment: Any update on this topic, i have the same problem on my MBP. PHPStorm keep indexing (result high CPU)... even for a small site with a total of 50 files.

Comment: I have the same issue phpStorm8 keeps indexing every minute for seconds without any file changes. Frozen input, unresponsive cursor. So annoying... I went back to 7.1 it works at least. The official support page asks for logs - built by 3rd party software. No thanks, I have no time to spend on that.

Comment: I ran into the same issue after upgrade to yosemite. The cpu usage was once more raising higher after switching to the (current newest) java 1.8.0_25, which was recommended by the vendor to solve the flickering issue while scrolling in editor.

Answer (score 14):

I've been working on a large number of git branches recently, and a coworker advised me to invalidate my cache & restart PHPStorm. It seems to have worked, but be warned - you will lose your local history.

In any case, File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is no quick easy answer here to fix your problem, because it can depend on many things, like OS version, JVM version, other software installed (you get my drift). If you open the IDE, and go to Help -> New Support Request, and open a ticket, one of our support engineers will be able to talk you through generating a summary of the system that will enable them to help you solve this problem.

I'm sorry I can't be more specifically helpful here, but usually in this case it's a JVM or OS problem that can be fixed quickly by the team once they get your system specs.

Gary

Answer (score 0):

Go into your settings, and under IDE Settings, click on "Editor"

Go to the -Virtual Space- heading, and make sure "Use soft wraps in editor" is UNticked

Comment: I ran into this after opening up a few minified+compiled JS files. Closing them appeared to solve the problem, so there's some validity to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was new plugins.
In setting disable newly install plugins.

Answer (score -1):

From the official [forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000048904-PhpStorm-2017-3-uses-100-CPU):

> Current tasks are displayed in a View > Status Bar (a bar in a bottom of IDE). It might show "indexing ..." or "scanning files to index".

close it works for me.