# PhpStorm - Huge use of CPU usage

Tags: phpstorm

What is up with PhpStorm? Are they quietly BitCoin mining in the background or something along those lines...

My CPU usage can range anything between 150% and 500%... and if I am using a laptop, it gets really warm and toasts my nads... which is unpleasant and they need constant re-arranging.

I am really thinking of changing IDE if this continues for the sake of my future children...

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

And for those of you who do not believe this hits 600% +...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phpstorm superslow - 282.8% CPU usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849090/phpstorm-superslow-282-8-cpu-usage)

Comment: 1) Collect performance logs/info 2) Submit Support ticket -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731 . There is universal recipe for solving your issue -- it's quite system and project dependant (active plugins; what sort of code you are working with (how it's written -- e.g. lots of Language Injection fragments), what language it is (usually JS generates more CPU usage) etc.). It's also possible that newer version has these issues resolved (try stable 2016.3.3 or upcoming 2017.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes I have some performance problems or strange bugs that are effectively related to a specific project.

And... there's a magic button in JetBrains IDEs to fix that.

As soon as I encounter a problem like that, my first reflex is to do `Files > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` and click `Invalidate and Restart`.

This will cleanup the index and other caches and rebuild them, often fixing a variety of problems. That's still quite rarely required, fortunately.

But in any case, just don't blame the IDE as a whole, JetBrains IDEs are actually not especially slow (sometimes the Swing UI can create this impression but in fact, there are fairly good in general) and will never consume that much CPU in a normal condition. As @LazyOne said, the problem can also come from a third-party extension or whatever. If the problem persists after a cache invalidation, follow its advices.

Comment: Just noticed that CPU cores were running quite hot.  Checked htop, PHPStorm was maxing out a bunch of cores.  I tried this Invalidate-and-Restart trick.  CPU ran hot while the cache was being rebuilt obviously, but they're fine now.  Handy tip.

Comment: Good tip, I have made this the official answer as it is a lot better than re-installing!

Answer (score 1):

After much bug testing I resolved this by nuking and re-installing my project. Still not sure what the cause of the problem was however the re-install did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

They now also have magic File > [Repair IDE...](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/repair-ide.htmlhttps://)

Worked for me even when cache invalidation didn't help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).